# Client name field is missing in the pcap - connection by DriverManager to MariaDB

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, wireshark

Writing with Java, I am using JDBC DriverManager Interface to connect MariaDB:

```
connectionUrl = jdbc:mysql://10.100.92.141:3306/mysql
sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
```

After the connection is established, I send some queries and the traffic is recorded to a pcap.

While opening the pcap, the field of "client_name" that should be: "MariaDB Connector/J" is missing.

How can I make the connection send also the client name field?

I added a screenshot of comparing two pcaps:

On the left: traffic that I sent manually to DB via DBeaver, there I can see connection attributes and there is the client name.

On the right: traffic that sent via Java code, there are no connection attributes:
[image]

Comment: I've never packet inspected this kind of stuff but I'd imagine the client would always be 'Java'

Comment: I don't think the mysql protocol has a field to send the client name

Comment: @nos it has. i added a screen shot

Comment: You should be using a connection URL starting with `jdbc:mariadb:`, not `jdbc:mysql:`. It is entirely possible right now you're connecting with MySQL Connector/J instead of MariaDB Connector/J.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution:

replace mysql driver with this driver: "mariadb-java-client-3.0.3.jar driver"

driverClassName: "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",

dbConnectionUrl: "jdbc:mariadb://${host}:${port}/${dbName}"